# Google Maps is not working in Qlikview tool

Tags: qlikview

We are using Google Maps in Qlikview (Business Intelligence tool). Recent days we are getting a pop-up error:

> "This site can't load google maps correctly do you own this website g.co/staticmaperror/key"

We need google support to sort out this issue.

Using the below script:

```
LOAD Quantity, Customer, City FROM [D:\Customer_info.xls] (biff, embedded labels, table is Sheet1$);
let noRows = NoOfRows('CustomerTable')-1;
for i=0 to $(noRows)
    let a=peek('Customer',$(i),'CustomerTable');
    let b=peek('City',$(i),'CustomerTable');
    let c=peek('Quantity',$(i),'CustomerTable'); 
    GeocodeResponse: LOAD status, '$(a)' as CustomerName, '$(b)' as CustomerCity, '$(c)' as CustomerQuantity, ([result/geometry/location/lat]) as latitude, ([result/geometry/location/lng]) as longitude FROM [maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/…, Table is [GeocodeResponse]);
    next i;
SET HidePrefix='_' ; // Field required for calculating best zoom level
_zoom_level: Load RecNo( ) as _zoom_level Autogenerate(max_zoom_level);
maptype: LOAD * INLINE [ Maptype roadmap mobile satellite terrain hybrid ];
gmap_key =“;
max_zoom_level = 14;
Def_zoom_level=7;
Def_map_size=400;
var_pi180= '=pi()/180';
var_lat_offset= '0';
var_mc2= '=256*pow(2,$(var_zoom))';
var_mc1= '=256*pow(2,($(var_zoom)-1))';
var_mid_lat= '=median(latitude)';
var_mid_long= '=median(longitude)';
map_size_x= '640';
map_size_y= '400';
```

Comment: How are you using Google maps? Extension or a text box/image? The error suggest that you need to add a valid API key to continue using Maps.

Comment: First, I have used Scatter Plot chart to display the google Map using API Key and extension aslo tried. Both Techniques are showing same error.

Comment: It was working fine until Sep (End of the Month) using the below script.

Comment: Are you sure that the API key is ok? Generate different API key and try. Also billing should be enabled inside Google  cloud project

Comment: The error is described on this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/error-messages

Comment: Please, do not post your code in comments: instead, format it properly directly by using the [edit] button on your question. Thank you.

Comment: I am sure about the Key because we were using until sep 2018 for 3 years.

Comment: Should i buy license for that

Comment: Depends on your usage. There is a free limit ("Free up to 25,000 map loads per day. $0.50 USD / 1,000 additional map loads, up to 100,000 daily, if billing is enabled") and when you go over the limit Google will charge you. Thats why they need Billing to be enabled